# .NET Core 2 MVC - Downloading file from Azure Blob Storage works in Google Chrome but not in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, azure-blob-storage

The HTML link to download:

```
<a asp-action="DownloadFile" asp-route-id="@Model.ID">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BlobName)</a>

Generated HTML link: http://localhost:50325/DebitMemos/DownloadFile/76
```

The corresponding controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile(int id)
    {
        var debitMemo = await _context.DebitMemo
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);

        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        try
        {
            CloudBlobContainer container = DebitMemo.GetAzureContainer();
            blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(debitMemo.BlobName);
            await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
            // Save blob contents to a file.
            await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(ms);

            Stream blobStream = await blockBlob.OpenReadAsync();

            return File(blobStream, blockBlob.Properties.ContentType, debitMemo.BlobName);
        }
        catch (StorageException)
        {
            return Content("File does not exist");
        }
   }
```

Clicking on the link in Chrome prompts for a location to download the file to and then successfully downloads it.

Internet Explorer (where I need the application to work), on the other hand, says "Do you want to open or save 76 (1.54 KB) from localhost?"

"76" in that example is the ID of the debitMemo, and I don't know why it's calling it that rather than the blobName. And then, when I click Save, it just says "76 could not be downloaded." with no other explanation.

Let me know if there is any other information I should provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Internet Explorer Could Not Download.

This issue can occur if the Index.dat file in the Temporary Internet Files folder or the Cookies folder has been marked with the Read Only attribute, or the Temporary Internet Files folder is too full.

There are some ways you could have a try.

1.To solve this issue, you could read this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/183506/error-message-internet-explorer-could-not-download). It may be related with IE settings.

2.Maybe you save the file in a **readonly** folder,so you can not save successfully. You could try to save as another folder.

3.You say you see the id rather than the blobName, you could set a break point to check the value of **debitMemo.BlobName** in your code. Please make sure  it is an exist blobName.

Besides, if I pass a blob name directly in GetBlockBlobReference method, it works fine. 
[image]

Comment: one moment, I was out sick and just got back to work!

Answer (score 4):

Do not use MemoryStream. If you do, you would have to manage that memory stream.

Instead, just open the stream to the blob and connect it to ASP.NET's response stream.

```
var stream = await blockBlob.OpenReadAsync();
return File(stream, blockBlob.Properties.ContentType, debitMemo.BlobName);
```